# WebJob Running for so long time for some messages and never finished status

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

1. For every 1000 messages 1 message is running for 20 minutes and more than that where other messages are completing in less than 1 sec. What could be the reason and I don't know whether it is going to be complete.
2. Some messages are going to "Never Finished" state other than Success and Failure. What could be the reason and I think my function has no issues if so we are logging it.

Answer (score 0):

If the message processing is taking a long time periodically (or not finishing at all), it must be that every now and then the operations in your job function take a long time or fail. All depends on what your job is actually doing internally. If it is going async in places, the SDK will continue to wait for it to return. We did add a new feature very recently **TimeoutAttribute** (see release notes: http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes). The Dashboard should show any function errors.

If you suspect that your job may be hanging/failing at certain places, you might try verifying locally that this is handled correctly by your logging etc. You could add Task.Delays or errors at various spots and verify that it's logged/handled correctly.